# How to display 2 sets of stacked data in one barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, combinedchart

So i'm creating an MI pack and i wanted to include a barplot that displays when something was submitted and who was at fault for lateness.
I have 5 columns of data which can be split into two sections:

Section 1 (submission time) = Pre 7am, 7am-9am, Post 9am

Section 2 (fault) = us, them
There are 6 rows of data (i.e., previous 6 months).

No problems with reading the data, manipulating it, changing the dates or formatting. Likewise no issues with creating barplots of either the whole set of data stacked, or each section stacked (which is what I want).

What i would like is for section 1 to be a stacked barplot, and next to it have section 2.

[Recreated in excel in case description not clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7WxY.jpg)

This is the code I have so far.
Downloading and manipulating data to suitable format

```
MIDF <- read.xlsx("C:/MISMM.xlsx", sheet = 11, startRow = 3, colNames = TRUE)
MDATE <- excel_numeric_to_date(MIDF$`Month./.Year`, date_system = "modern", include_time = "false")
MDATE <- format(as.Date(MDATE), "%m-%Y")
MIDF <- cbind(MDATE, MIDF[2:19])
MIDF <- tail(MIDF, 6)
```

This is all 5 columns stacked

```
LAFU <- MIDF %>% select (9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
LAFUa <- MIDF %>% select(1)
LAFUa <- (t(LAFUa))
LAFU <- (t(LAFU))
LAFUCHART <- barplot(LAFU, 
         names.arg=LAFUa, 
         main = "Lates and who is at fault",
         col=c("#1488CA", "#6B7E87", "#AA0B3C", "#FDC41F",  "#85C9F0"), 
         legend = rownames(LAFU), 
         beside = FALSE)
```

And this the two sections seperate

```
LAFUresub <- MIDF %>% select (9, 10, 11)
LAFUerror <- MIDF %>% select (12, 13)
LAFUa <- MIDF %>% select(1)
LAFUa <- (t(LAFUa))
LAFUresub <- (t(LAFUresub))
LAFUerror <- (t(LAFUerror))

 LAFUresubBP <- barplot(LAFUresub, 
    names.arg=LAFUa, 
    main = "Lates",
    col=c("#1488CA", "#6B7E87", "#AA0B3C"), 
    legend = rownames(LAFUresub), 
    beside = FALSE)

 LAFUerrorBP <- barplot(LAFUerror, 
    names.arg=LAFUa, 
    main = "Who is at fault",
    col=c("#FDC41F",  "#85C9F0"), 
    legend = rownames(LAFUerror), 
    beside = FALSE)
```

and finally - my attempt at having them replicate the picture. It's a bit lame but i honestly have no idea where to start.

```
LAFUTIME <- t(group_by(MIDF %>% select(9,10,11)))
LAFUERROR <- t(group_by(MIDF %>% select(12, 13)))
LAFUDATE <- t(MIDF %>% select(1))
test<-rbind(LAFUTIME, LAFUERROR)
barplot(LAFUTIME %>% LAFUERROR)
```

any help greatly appreciated. 
David

Here is some code for a dataframe that is comparable to what I am using, if that will help.

```
pre7am <- c(1,2,3,2,1,3)
SamNam<- c(2,4,3,6,5,3)
post9am<- c(1,2,1,0,1,0)
us <-     c(0,0,1,3,2,0)
them <-   c(4,8,6,5,5,6)
dates <- c("Jul18", "Aug18", "Sept18", "Oct18", "Nov18", "Dec18")

DF <- data.frame(pre7am, SamNam, post9am, us, them, row.names = dates)
```

Comment: Could you post some data? if you need help posting the data, use `dput`. I think I know how to do it.

Comment: Using the below code (sorry it's not formatted well in the comment box) will give you a dataframe comparable to what i am using ------------ pre7am <- c(1,2,3,2,1,3)
SamNam<- c(2,4,3,6,5,3)
post9am<- c(1,2,1,0,1,0)
us <-     c(0,0,1,3,2,0)
them <-   c(4,8,6,5,5,6)
dates <- c("Jul18", "Aug18", "Sept18", "Oct18", "Nov18", "Dec18")

DF <- data.frame(pre7am, SamNam, post9am, us, them, row.names = dates)

Comment: Please use "Sep18" as opposed to "Sept18" as date abbreviations in R are three letters for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used the following, which is pretty close:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

DF %>% 
mutate(Dates = rownames(DF),
Dates = factor(Dates, levels = c("Jul18","Aug18", "Sep18", "Oct18", "Nov18", "Dec18"))) %>% 
gather(vartype, value, -Dates) %>% 
mutate(Subsection =paste("Subsection", abs(as.numeric(grepl("am", vartype)) - 1) + 1)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Subsection,value, fill = vartype, col = vartype)) + 
geom_col() +
facet_grid(.~Dates)
```

So first we move the `Dates` from rownames to an actual variable. Then we make sure that the `Dates` are actually an ordered factor (needed for `facet_grids`). Then we format data into long format using `gather`. `Subsection` is created based on the two kinds of stacks you want, where we check if "am" is in `vartype` (boolean) and then we create a function where we create `Subsection1` if "am" is in `vartype` and `Subsection2` if "am" is not present. Then since we have the values for column heights, then we use `geom_col`. We also use `facet_grid` to break the plots by `Dates` and arrange accordingly.

Comment: That is great and well explained, have migrated it over and adapted it for other data and it's working well!